# Custom RMSPE loss function in keras

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to define my own loss function in keras which is Root Mean Squared Percentage Error.  RMSPE is defined as :  
[image: equation]  
I have defined my loss function as:

```
from keras import backend as K
def rmspe(y_true, y_pred):
    sum = K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square( (y_true - y_pred) /
          K.clip(K.abs(y_true),K.epsilon(),None) ), axis=-1) )
    return sum*100.
```

But after a few iterations it is giving me loss value as nan. Can someone point out what am i doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: Which backend do you use?

Comment: i am using tensorflow

Comment: Have you checked if your data doesn't contain `Nan`s?

Comment: Yes i have checked. There are no nans

Comment: Is your data normalized? What is the `min` and `max` of your `y`s?

Answer (score 1):

It's good that you're clipping the denominator. But epsilon in the tensorflow backend is 1e-7 when I check on my machine. So you can still blow up your gradient by ten million when you divide by the clipped value. What you want to do is **clip your gradient** which you can do with either the `clipvalue` or `clipnorm` arguments to your optimizer:

```
optimizer = SGD(clipvalue=10.0)
```

or

```
optimizer = SGD(clipnorm=2.0)
```

You have to play with the value a bit depending on how many output variables you have and how much noise is in your data.

Answer (score 0):

When your denominator is 0, that will be Nan. Consider plus a small number on your denominator, like 0.0000001.

Comment: K.clip is already doing that. You can check <https://keras.io/backend/>  what clip does.

Answer (score 0):

```
def rmspe(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square((y_true - y_pred) / y_true)))
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.

Comment: This is what ultimately worked for me but there was some more step involved. I don't know what is the policy about answering question + attributing a bounty if I give the answer myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think I should answer this myself after some extensive reasearch and discussion. I have found two working alternatives to optimise RMPSE in tensorflow+keras.

The first one is a "trick" : the RMSPE is equivalent to a weighted RMSE with weights $1/y_i^2$. So the first option is to use 'mse' as loss and add a sample_weight parameter as $1/np.square(y_train)$. This is working quite well but can be a bit cumbersome once you want to use other weights / loss functions in your architecture.

The alternative as mentionned by Gregory Lopes is to use:

```
def rmspe(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square((y_true - y_pred) / y_true)))
```

It is important to note that for both these options to work you need to remove targets that are equal to zero or nan. Checking for nan (y_train.isna().sum()) or for 0 (y_train==0).sum() is rather easy and will help you avoid some headaches.

As to why the mentionned solution isn't working. It seems to come from numerical instabilities due to the cliping function. Changing the clipping behavior will give different errors. I didn't completely understand as to why it's happening, but removing it appears to solve the problem. Somehow the security put in place to avoid errors is causing them.